# Sonata Admin Custom list field template contains link to admin edit object

Tags: symfony, sonata

I have an admin class of an object of class Car. This object is in relation with Person or Organisation.

I know how to add a column for Person and Organisation, and i have a link to the edit object

```
$listMapper
->add('person', null, array('admin_code' => 'appli.admin.person'))
->add('factory', null, array('admin_code' => 'appli.admin.factory'))
```

This create a link (

However i want just one column. I make this :

```
$listMapper->add('name',null,array('label'=>'Name','template'=>'AcmeBundle:Admin/Car/list_name.html.twig'))
```

But in my template i want something like this but i don't understand how make the link to the edit object :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field%}
{% if object.getPerson %}
    {% set urlObject = 'linkToAdminEditPerson' %}
{% elseif object.getFactory %}
    {% set urlObject = 'linkToAdminEditFactory' %}
{% endif %}
<a href="{{ urlObject }}">{{ object.name }}</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming both objects have a `name` property:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field %}
    {% if object.getPerson is defined %}
        {% set objectRoute = 'person_edit' %}
    {% elseif object.getFactory is defined %}
        {% set objectRoute = 'factory_edit' %}
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{{ path(objectRoute, { id: object.id }) }}">{{ object.name }}</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Note that sonata admin bundle creates the edit route based on the `$baseRouteName` property of the admin class, appending the action name.

Comment: Thank you but it not exactly what i want. The link must to go the AdminObjectEdit (not the same of the list). Something like this, but it's not ok

`<a href="{{ admin.generateUrl('appli.car.edit', {id: object.person.id}) }}">{{ object.name }}</a>`

I have this error : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("unable to find the route `appli.admin.car|appli.admin.person`") in AcmeBundle:Admin/Car:list_name.html.twig at line 8

Comment: Edited answer according to your comment

Answer (score 4):

1. Firstly use a custom template for your field:

   ```
   $listMapper
        ->add('_action', 'actions',
           array(
              'label' => 'Person',
              'actions' => array('usage' => array('template' =>'MyBundleBundle:CRUD:edit_url.html.twig'))
           )
    );
   ```
2. In admin class create a function that generates a sonata edit url:

   ```
   public function generateEditUrl($name, $object, $parameters = array(), $absolute = false){
       $classname = $object->getNode()->getPropertyValue('phpcr:class');
       $admin = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getAdminByClass($classname);
       $url = $admin->generateObjectUrl($name, $object, $parameters, $absolute);
       return $url;
   }
   ```
3. Create "edit_url.html.twig" template

   ```
   {% if object.person is defined and object.person is not empty %}
       <a href="{{ admin.generateEditUrl('edit', object.person, {}, true) }}" target="_blank" title="Edit {{ object.person.title }}">
           <i class="icon-edit"></i>{{ object.person.title }}
       </a>
   {% endif %}
   ```